# Mongo `$graphLookup` restricting breadth

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of comments for a forum-like app; each comment has a `parentId`, and there can be comment threads of arbitrary length. What I want to do is, starting from a root comment, get a single chain of sub-comments. I tried something like this, but this returns a whole tree of comments:

```
$graphLookup: {
  from: "comments",
  startWith: "$_id",
  connectFromField: "_id",
  connectToField: "parentId",
  as: "thread",
  maxDepth: 10,
}
```

Is there a way to limit the breadth to 1 at each level, so starting with the root comment, it finds only 1 child of the root, and then finds only 1 child of that comment, and so on? As far as I can tell, I cannot do this with $graphLookup, but maybe there is a way to do this with other aggregation stages? Or will I have to make multiple queries from my server?

Comment: I should add that once I figure this out, my next goal would be to pick the comment with the most likes at each level, rather than just picking an arbitrary comment. Any help with this would also be much appreciated!